# Erro no Mongoose ou nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

estou desenvolvendo um script simples, porem travei em um erro que não consigo entender o motivo, Criei um Model e aparentemente o erro ocorre sempre que tento acessar.

node:

```js
router.get('/postagens', (req, res) => {
    Postagem.find().populate("categorias").sort({data: "desc"}).then((postagens) => {
        res.render("admin/postagens", {postagens: postagens})
    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash("error_msg", "ouve um erro ao listar postagens")
        res.redirect("/admin")
    })
         
})
```

Mongoose:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Postagem = new Schema({
    titulo:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    descricao:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    conteudo:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    categoria:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Categorias",
        required: true
    },
    data:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }

})

mongoose.model("postagens", Postagem)
```

O erro que é apresentado é o seguinte:

> ReferenceError: Postagem is not defined
>       at router.get (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/ericoEstudos/blogapp/routes/admin.js:107:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
>       at router (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at app.use (/home/ericocalasans/Documents/nodejs/filanave/ericoEstudos/blogapp/app.js:49:13)

Answer (score 0):

no fim mete assim :

```
const postagens = mongoose.model("postagens", Postagem);

module.exports = postagens;
```

Comment: O usuário relatou um erro que não consegue entender o motivo. O código resolve o erro, mas não responde a dúvida. Explique o que significa `module.exports` o porque de usar, como usar e qual a diferença para o `module.default`. Agregue valor a sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você criou o Schema mas não exportou essa instância. Basicamente, teu `schema` precisa ser "escutado" aonde ele for chamado, para isso, você precisa `exportar` esta instância. Para fazer esse `export`, se usa o `module.exports`. Neste teu caso, para que se consiga usar o `Postagem`, você precisa colocar no teu arqquivo do `esquema`

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("postagens", Postagem)
```

Dessa maneira você pode realizer um `require` desse módulo e usar os métodos do `mongoose` pertencentes a este esquema.

Vale lembrar que essas implementação se tornam muito mais fáceis com `ES6`. Já que você pode exportar teu `model` através de

```
export default mongoose.model("postagens", Postagem)
```

E aonde você faria o `require`, você colocaria

```
import Postagem from '../meu_arquivo.js'
```

Tem bastante conteúdo sobre `ES6` na web, dá uma pesquisada e uma boa estudada. Isso vai te ajudar muito no teu desenvolvimento, até porque, se formos dar uma geral nas `features` do `ES6` ficaria muito longa a resposta e perderia o foco da tua dúvida.

Resumindo, precisa exportar um módulo (função)? Deve usar `module.exports`. Ah, caso tenha mais do que uma função para exportar, você pode simplesmente fazer

```
module.exports = {
   function funcao1() {}
   function funcao2() {}
}
```

ou

```
function funcao1() {}
function funcao2() {}
module.exports = {
  funcao1,
  funcao2
}
```